# Oracle column not available in subsequent transactions

Tags: database, oracle, transactionscope

For our ASP.NET application we use a C# console application to maintain our Oracle and SQLServer databases.  Individual scripts are loaded and run in numerical order (the script names have the number), and committed when the script is complete.

This is a legacy application, and we are moving away from this format in the future, however for now we need to maintain it with as little modification as possible.

Recently, we added two columns to our DB_VERSION table: APP_MAJOR and APP_MINOR.  This addition was done in one of our scripts, with the purpose being to allow us to track what release of our product the database was last updated to.

When each script completes execution and is committed (using IDbContext and IDbTransaction), the application updates the DB_VERSION table with the major/minor version of the application along with the number of the script.  Prior to adding the Major/Minor columns, the application just updated the script number.

In SQLServer, there are no issues at all - when the application completes, the DB_VERSION table properly indicates the version of the app.  However, in Oracle, the APP_MAJOR and APP_MINOR columns are never updated.

I have tracked this to the query we use that verifies whether or not the table as the new columns - and even after script execution is complete, the new columns are not showing up.  It appears that Oracle is caching the previous query so never makes the new columns available for update (though the Version column that was always updated continues to be updated properly).

We have tried manually closing the connection, completely terminating the context and putting in a 5 second wait period to allow the pools to expire (I know, I know), changing the structure of the script itself to use straight DDL - all to no avail.  Adding a statement to clear the Oracle cache also failed because of a permissions error.

I would put code here for your review, but there are too many places where there could be a problem - I'm hoping someone can provide a general direction for us to take.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you think there are too many problematic places split the question into too many and post your code. We can't help you without any code example. And people will be least interested in reading essays!! No offence!!

Comment: I agree that is hard to suggest anything without more information or code. (How are you connecto to Oracle, Oracle version, driver version, etc.). Also some of the text in the question is not needed. Let's start by seeing the query you think is the problem and the code where it's being executed.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but I'm fairly confident the problem is not caching.  Oracle automatically commits before it executes any DDL.  If your `ALTER TABLE` script really did succeed, then you will always see the new table structure.  It's more likely that your script fails to add the two columns, but for some reason doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: So you have a statement like `UPDATE db_version SET col1=1, col2=5` and only `col1` is updated?